# Clear "no switchport" command from cisco device interface

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

How can clear "no switchport" command from cisco devices interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go into interface mode and write "switchport".

Example:

```
conf t
interface Gi1/0/15
switchport
end
wr
```